# Top 5 values in SQL and accumulated betting

Tags: sql

I'm not the best at coding in SQL, so I hope you can help me. I have made this dataset with af bunch of results and predicted possibilities for the outcome.

[image: Dataset]

I want to choose the top 5 best bets in every stage for each season. Can somebody help me with?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: I'm using Tableplus, but I'm open for suggestions to other free programs, which is compatible with Mac

Comment: @ChristofferHolmeskovRasmusse . . . Tableplus is a GUI interface to databases.  It is not the database itself.  What database is it talking to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have analytic functions available, here is a general query which should work on most databases:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY season, stage ORDER BY "best bet" DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, so I don't think I have a analytic function available. Do you have any suggestions for another dbms I can use for MAC?

Comment: Any recent version of SQL Server, Oracle, or Postgres should do fine.  MySQL version 8+ or later should also work.  Handling your problem without analytic functions can be a real pain.